# Match returning #N/A

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a value in cell G5:

```
I~W478i~100
```

And an array in F31:F43:

```
I~W478i~100
II~W707a~79
I~W621c~97.5
II~W693a~81.5
I~W452n~80
I~W693a~71.5
II~W707a~64
I~W478i~75
II~W724a~100
I~W707a~79
I~W693a~91.5
I~W587a~69
III~W724a~75
```

I am the MATCH formula to determine the position of the value in the array:

```
=MATCH(G5,F31:F43,0)
```

This is returning #N/A.

I believe that the value in F31 should match that in G5. To double check, I create another formula:

```
=IF(G5=F31,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Which returns TRUE. However the MATCH function still returns #N/A. I have checked both the value and the array and both are Data Type "General".

What are the possible causes of this issue?

Comment: If you ask me it's an Excel bug. The "0" flag doesn't seem to work at all. I tried multiple ways around the issue and it always gives me the "N/A". I suggest you just remove the optional third parameter or use the "-1" or "1" parameters as they seem to work fine.

Comment: see answer for why, but use `=MATCH(SUBSTITUTE(G5,"~","~~"),F31:F43,0)`

Comment: Not sure why, but the problem is the tilde (~) characters.  If you replace them with something else, it works fine.  I see Blackwood already has a solution.

Comment: @Bandersnatch see the answer below for why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the "~" character is a special character when used in the first parameter of the `MATCH` function. It is used to indicate that the character following the "~" is not a wildcard character (see the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)). If you want the first parameter to include "~" characters, you need use two "~" characters.

So if you change the value in G5 from `I~W478i~100` to `I~~W478i~~100`, your `MATCH` function will return 1 instead of #N/A.

As Scott Craner (thanks Scott) points out in a comment on the question, you can also leave G5 as it is, and use `SUBSTITUTE` to insert the extra "~" characters as part of the formula.

```
=MATCH(SUBSTITUTE(G5,"~","~~"),F31:F43,0)
```

Note that if the values in F31:F43 might also contain `"*"` or `"?"` characters, you will also need to change every `"*"` to `"~*"` and every `"?"` to `"~?"`.